# Terminal based application with curl

Tags: http, curl, terminal

I'm planning to do website that is terminal-accessible only (through curl)

My plan is to make interface pretty much like wttr.in

So what exactly should my backend return to support `curl` command in terminal? Is it `plaintext` response? What should I focus on to support all types of terminals? (maybe with ommiting the powershell as I read that it has some problems with curl and wttr.in especially)

Comment: You can divide terminals generally into 3 types: VT100 compatible terminals, DOS/Windows terminal and everything else. Google "VT100 escape sequence" for how a website like wttr.in outputs for the terminal. You can even dump the output to a file and examine it in a text or hex editor to see what it does. It's essentially just an ANSI text file

Comment: .. Oh, that reminds me. You can also google "ANSI art" to see what people can do with VT100 escape sequences - it's like ASCII art only more colourful